# snap store node js not let me install angular cli

Tags: command-line, apt, nodejs, 20.04

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I installed the node from snap store. Now when I am trying to install the angular cli, it doesn't let me do that

```
2020/03/28 11:51:57.975509 cmd_run.go:884: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create "/nonexistent/snap/node/2622": mkdir /nonexistent: permission denied
cannot create user data directory: /nonexistent/snap/node/2622: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @angular/cli@9.1.0 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@9.1.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-28T06_22_03_201Z-debug.log
```

Anyone have any idea for this, this is look like permission issue. How I can install the ng cli into my 20.04 system.

Comment: Remove the -g from your install no need sudo

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is, that snap does not allow installed snap packages to write to `/usr/local`. Unfortunately this is the default location from global installed npm packages.

You can solve this issue in 3 simple steps by changing the default location from global installed npm packages to one directory, where the snap (in this case node) is allowed to write.

At first we createthe new directory for our future global installed npm packages:

```bsh
mkdir ~/.local/npm
```

Now we need to add the new created folder to our `PATH`. For this open or create a `~/.bashrc` file and add this line:

```bsh
export PATH=~/.local/npm/bin:$PATH
```

Do you noticed the new `/bin` folder and wonder why this one is here? Npm will create it and it will contain the executeables/syslinks for global installed packages. Without it, you would not be able to run `ng` in your terminal.

The last step is to override the default npm global location (npm calls this "prefix"):

```bsh
npm config set prefix '~/.local/npm'
```

Now you can install npm packages global. `npm install -g @angular/cli` should now work.

To test if everything is working correctly, run `ng version` after you installed it globally with npm.

I used the following source for my answer: https://github.com/mixonic/docs.npmjs.com/blob/master/content/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions.md

Comment: I wasted my lot of time playing with Snap for dotnet. I finally remove snapd and use the apt to install thing. work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the install command with sudo? I've run into this issue sometimes with NPM, giving it a swift kick in the rear with sudo usually does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was using

```
sudo npm install  -g @angular/cli
```

After I have removed sudo from this its went on and installed the angular.

```
npm install  -g @angular/cli
```